# Problem with downloading large file from internet

Tags: wget, download, maven

Since a while ago, whenever I am downloading a large file with maven it takes a long time. I also tried with just `wget` and still had the same problem. It will freeze for 10 or more minutes after reaching 99%:

```
$ wget http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/stable/site/plugins/org.scala-ide.scala.compiler_2.10.4.v20140209-180020-VFINAL-b66a39653b.jar
--2016-05-26 10:46:24--  http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e38/scala210/stable/site/plugins/org.scala-ide.scala.compiler_2.10.4.v20140209-180020-VFINAL-b66a39653b.jar
Resolving download.scala-ide.org (download.scala-ide.org)... 128.179.67.43
Connecting to download.scala-ide.org (download.scala-ide.org)|128.179.67.43|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide/sdk/e38/scala210/stable/site/plugins/org.scala-ide.scala.compiler_2.10.4.v20140209-180020-VFINAL-b66a39653b.jar [following]
--2016-05-26 10:46:24--  http://downloads.typesafe.com/scalaide/sdk/e38/scala210/stable/site/plugins/org.scala-ide.scala.compiler_2.10.4.v20140209-180020-VFINAL-b66a39653b.jar
Resolving downloads.typesafe.com (downloads.typesafe.com)... 52.85.246.199, 52.85.246.219, 52.85.246.38, ...
Connecting to downloads.typesafe.com (downloads.typesafe.com)|52.85.246.199|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 18127195 (17M) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: ‘org.scala-ide.scala.compiler_2.10.4.v20140209-180020-VFINAL-b66a39653b.jar.1’

99% [===========================================================================================================================================================> ] 18,127,056  --.-K/s  eta 0s      
99% [===========================================================================================================================================================> ] 18,127,056  --.-K/s  eta 0s      
99% [===========================================================================================================================================================> ] 18,127,056  --.-K/s  eta 0s      
99% [===========================================================================================================================================================> ] 18,127,056  --.-K/s  eta 0s      
99% [===========================================================================================================================================================> ] 18,127,056  --.-K/s  eta 0s      
99% [===========================================================================================================================================================> ] 18,127,056  --.-K/s  eta 0s      
99% [===========================================================================================================================================================> ] 18,127,056  --.-K/s  eta 0s
```

If I connect to another machine over `ssh` and try the same thing it works fine so there must be a problem with my system. How can I fix or debug this? I tried restarting but the problem persists.

I have Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ uname -a
Linux hudect-PC 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:37:48 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

This isn't a space or inode issue:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      355698604 199482588 138124448  60% /
```

and

```
$ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      22601728 1604814 20996914    8% /
```

Comment: Did you try curl and/or GET instead?